# Sorting an ArrayList of Person with java collections

Tags: java, sorting, collections, io

Below the code I am using works just fine and outputs the names except that the sort method is not working. I expected "Collections.sort(nameFromText);" to sort the ArrayList in alphabetical order by first name.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create and populate text file
    Writer textFile = new FileWriter("names.txt");
    String[] nameArray = new String[] { "Tina Tully\n", "Bill Simpson\n",
            "Dana Smith\n", "Ralph Andrews\n", "Greg Smithers\n",
            "Lisa Krump\n", "Gill Bitters\n", "Barbara West\n",
            "Sandra McDonald\n", "Bart Willis\n", "Bucky Zimmerman\n",
            "Richard Vicks\n", "Velma Tarp\n", "Winslow Tunnell\n",
            "Andrew Letterman\n", "Betty Trump\n", "Waldo Smith\n",
            "Kyle Ronno\n", "Vivian West\n", "Wendy Tunnell\n" };
    generateText(textFile, nameArray);

    // Create object of previously created text file
    Scanner pullFile = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

    // Create 20 Person Objects and add to ArrayList data structure with
    // name variables assigned to values from text file
    ArrayList<Person> nameFromText = new ArrayList<Person>();
    fillArrayList(nameFromText, pullFile);

    // Sort ArrayList
    Collections.sort(nameFromText);

    // Print ArrayList
    printNamesFromObjects(nameFromText);
}

private static void printNamesFromObjects(ArrayList<Person> namesFromText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        System.out.println(namesFromText.get(i).name);
    }
}

private static void fillArrayList(ArrayList<Person> nameFromText,
        Scanner pullFile) {
    while (pullFile.hasNext()) {
        Person obj = new Person(pullFile.nextLine());
        nameFromText.add(obj);
    }
}

private static void generateText(Writer textFile, String[] nameArray)
        throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        textFile.write(new String(nameArray[i]));
    }
    textFile.close();
}
```

Comment: You'll find this useeful. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/  and http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method expects the element of the list it is sorting to be comparable. Either the element type `T` should implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, or you should use the overloaded [`sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method, that takes a generic [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instance.

In the code below, you are satisfying neither of the above conditions. Neither your `Person` class implements `Comparable`, nor you are passing any `Comparator` instance.

```
ArrayList<Person> nameFromText = new ArrayList<Person>();
fillArrayList(nameFromText, pullFile);
// Sort ArrayList
Collections.sort(nameFromText);  // How to sort?
```

You should create a `Comparator` for your `Person` class to tell the `sort()` method how to sort it (may be on String stored in Person class)

Here's how you implement a generic comparator:

```
public class PersonNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

And then your `Collections.sort()` method invocation should be like: -

```
Collections.sort(nameFromText, new PersonNameComparator());
```

Comment: @DavidTunnell Your're welcome.. You can also google - "Difference between Comparator and Comparable` to get more information.. `Comparable` is also used for this purpose.. But `Comparator` is wider, as you can create multiple sorting logics..

Comment: I think you have a typo on your code. Shouldn't it be: `... (Person) o` **1** `; ... Person p2 = (Person) o` **2** `;` ?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can implement Comparable interface directly in Person class and override 'compareTo(Object obj) ' method. In this case you would not need to create new class for comparator. And this behaves like inbuilt sorting.

Comment: +1 Thats a valid point.. But you should prefer `Comparator` over `Comparable`. That way you can have multiple sorting logics for your class..

Comment: Yes,  as comparator give you the flexibility when there are more than one sorting candidates.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<String> inputString =  Arrays.asList("Sijan", "Sudeep", "Parasar", "Raj Kumar");
Collections.sort(inputString);
System.out.println(inputString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using Java 8 then use one liner **Lambda Expression**

```
ArrayList<Person> nameFromText = new ArrayList<Person>();
fillArrayList(nameFromText, pullFile);
nameFromText.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

**use Collections.sort(managerNameList);**

```
ArrayList<String> managerNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    managerNameList.add("antesh");
    managerNameList.add("Lalit");
    managerNameList.add("Gokul");
    managerNameList.add("Ajay");

    System.out.println("Arraylist before sorting");    
    for(String name: managerNameList)
    {    
        System.out.println(name);           
    }

    Collections.sort(managerNameList);

    System.out.println("Arraylist after sorting");    
    for(String name: managerNameList)
    {    
        System.out.println(name);           
    }
```