# Java: How to sort custom type ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, quicksort, mergesort

I have a custom type `Position(x,y,z)`,now I create a `ArrayList<Position>`, i want to sort this array ordered by the value of z, from small to bigger,how can i do that using `Collections.sort`or is there any other efficient sorting method?

When I try to use

```
public class PositionComparator implements Comparator<Position> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Position o1, Position o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.height().compareTo(o2.height());

        }

    }
```

get an error

```
Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an ArrayList of Person with java collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771534/sorting-an-arraylist-of-person-with-java-collections)

Comment: @Rohit Jain if my z is a double type, i get an error of `Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double`

Comment: try , return (int)(o1.height - o2.height());

Answer (score 8):

try

```
Collections.sort(SortList, new Comparator<Position>(){
            public int compare(Position p1, Position p2) {
                return p1.z- p2.z;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Collections.sort
```

for example

```
class User {

    String name;
    String age;

    public User(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ComparatorUser implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        User user0 = (User) arg0;
        User user1 = (User) arg1;

        int flag = user0.getAge().compareTo(user1.getAge());
        if (flag == 0) {
            return user0.getName().compareTo(user1.getName());
        } else {
            return flag;
        }
    }

}
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List userlist = new ArrayList();
        userlist.add(new User("dd", "4"));
        userlist.add(new User("aa", "1"));
        userlist.add(new User("ee", "5"));
        userlist.add(new User("bb", "2"));
        userlist.add(new User("ff", "5"));
        userlist.add(new User("cc", "3"));
        userlist.add(new User("gg", "6"));

        ComparatorUser comparator = new ComparatorUser();
        Collections.sort(userlist, comparator);

        for (int i = 0; i < userlist.size(); i++) {
            User user_temp = (User) userlist.get(i);
            System.out.println(user_temp.getAge() + "," + user_temp.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this (just an example I cut and past but same idea) for descending sort:

```
@Override
public int compare(Member m1, Member m2) {

    double fit1 = m1.getFitness() ;
    double fit2 = m2.getFitness() ;
    if (fit2>fit1)
            return 1;
    else if (fit2<fit1)
            return -1;
    else
            return  0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your `Comparator`, which will compare the value of the `z` attribute.