# Sort an ArrayList of Strings that are numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

What is the fastest way to sort an `ArrayList<String>` (in descending/ascending manner) that contains numbers, eg: `{ "12", "3.5", "188", "33.03" }` ? Does `Collections` have a built-in method for this? Currently I am copying the `ArrayList`'s contents to `ArrayList<Double>` and then using `Collections.Sort()` method and then putting it back to the initial array. Is there a faster way?

Comment: You could implement your own Comparator, not sure if faster though.

Comment: why do you want to insert numbers as string in an arraylist

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Long story short: maintaining somebody else's code.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas I agree, if it were me, I would make them all doubles

Comment: Check this answer [here][1]. It works for every type of variables.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771571/4096270

Comment: fastest in terms of CPU cycles or developer cycles ?

Comment: In terms of CPU primarily. But would be nice if it's a shorter code as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement your own comparator, and use it on your list.
You have to use BigDecimal, because you can have problems with loss of precision. You can use double, if your numbers are quire small precision.

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String, String> {

    public int compare(String o1, String o2){
        return new BigDecimal(o1).compareTo(new BigDecimal(o2));
    }

}
...
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: Best Java 1.7 solution! Except you can use `Double.parseDouble()` instead `BigDecimal` if you know the values are of limited precision.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `Comparator.comparing(Double::parseDouble)` to quickly create a comparator using `parseDouble`. This should (see below) call the function just once for each entry, and not once for each pair.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList( "12", "3.5", "188", "33.03" );
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Double::parseDouble));
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[3.5, 12, 33.03, 188]
```

*Update:* Well, I *thought* this would call the comparator function just once for each element, like using a `key`-function in Python, but after a quick test using a function increasing a counter each time it is called, the function is called just as often as using an old-style "pair"-comparator. Still, a bit shorter...

Comment: Thank you. Although it is less code to write, I use Java 7, and as I understood, List doesn't have sort() method in version 7, right? Any workarounds?

Comment: You have to solutions, just like in older Java versions. Either you create a comparator, like in above example, or you have to make all your collection objects implement Comparable, and then use Collections.sort() :) So no, List has no sort method:) Any why? Because it is an iterface, and sometimes list does not have to be indexed.

Comment: @Ben In Java 8, [`List` has a `sort` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 4):

Try following code:

```
String test[] = {"12", "3.5", "188", "33.03"};
double numbers[] = new double[test.length];
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
     numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(test[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(numbers);
for (double i : numbers) {
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output :**

```
3.5
12.0
33.03
188.0
```

Comment: Indeed, why? I'm trying it now

Comment: thats just the way the author did it, I didnt downvote though

Comment: Pretty much what I did, yes, but there might be a faster way.

Comment: You can use comparator but I think this is the faster way. And yes why downvotes?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `Float`s here due to the possible loss of accuracy (depending of course on the input values) but in principle this should be fine.

Comment: Yes `floats` can be changed to `double`.

Comment: i think competitor user giving down votes to increase their chances!

Answer (score 4):

I think your current approach is probably fine, I would avoid using a custom `Comparator` because you would end up converting the same string into a numeric value multiple times (each time the sorting algorithm wants to compare 2 values) rather than just once as you do now.

Comment: Doesn't the OPs method risk ending up with "0.0999999999123" in the list when the original element was "0.1"?

Comment: The point about multiple conversions is a good one; one solution may be to save the converted values to a map and then check that. Which solution is faster however is a totally different question...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.sort()` on `List<String>`, String is `Comparable`, but that comparison won't give you the right result.

Also you can define your own `Comparator`, and pass it to `Collections.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sortedset interface which enables you the sorted data during the time of entering the data.Better implement your own comparator which will be little beneficial i believe.